# magento 2 : How we can load product by sku in root file

Tags: magento2

i'm using magento 2 and i've to update particular product by sku,

i've used below code to load but it is taking too much time

```
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $productRepository->get(trim($sku));
```

is there any other solution to load product from root which take less then above code,

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repository`(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository)` always faster process for getting data.But donot know why is running show at  your system.Please run complier at system

So, Let try use Model class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` instead of
`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository`.

> ```
> $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
> $productModel = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
> $product = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
> ```

Please  try this

Comment: cool !! !

it's  works